# Should database schema changes increment the major version in Semantic Versioning?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

[Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/) says:

> For this system to work, you first need to declare a public API

My web application does not expose any public API, however it uses a database. Can the database schema be considered as the public API and then should a change in the database schema increment the major version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/mojombo/semver/issues/90) the answer is **yes**. The database schema can be considered as the *public API*.